# use of MultiThread with boost in VC++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am new to boost, C++ and threading, I am trying to use thread using boost library, but I am not able to access function through objects.

Here is what I am doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using namespace std;
class myclass
{
    int a,b;
    public:
    void print_a();
    void print_b();
};

void myclass::print_a()
{
 for(int i=1;i<1000000;++i) cout<<"printing a"<<endl;
}
void myclass::print_b()
{
    for(int i=1;i<1000000;++i) cout<<"printing b"<<endl;
}

void print_x()
{
    for(int i=1;i<1000000;++i) cout<<"printing x"<<endl;
}

void print_y()
{
    for(int i=1;i<1000000;++i) cout<<"printing y"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    myclass obj;
    boost::thread thread_a(obj.print_a);
    boost::thread thread_b(obj.print_b);
    boost::thread thread_x(print_x);
    boost::thread thread_y(print_y);
    thread_a.join();
    thread_b.join();
    thread_x.join();
    thread_y.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Error when calling `boost::thread thread_a(obj.print_a)` is a `pointer to a bound function may only be called to use this function` and same with thread_b but for thread_x and thread_y it is working properly.
What am I missing, please guide me

Thank You
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there is a new syntax I don't know about, you cannot pass `obj.print_a` as a "runnable" you have to do

```
boost::bind( &myclass::print_a, &obj );
```

or `std::bind` if your version supports it.

As it happens `boost::thread` has a multi-parameter version that does the bind for you. Thus when you create the thread

```
boost::thread thread_a( &myclass::print_a, &obj );
```

In C++11 you can also use lambdas

```
[&obj]{ obj.print_a(); }
```

thus in one line

```
boost::thread thread_a( [&obj]{ obj.print_a(); } );
```

or if that looks too messy assign the lambda (you can use auto of course as its type) and pass that in a separate line.

Comment: Also `boost::thread thread_a(&myclass::print_a, &obj);` should work, i.e. no need for `bind`.

Comment: thank you. added it to my answer. Also corrected to &obj as bind passes by value and it's simpler than boost::ref(obj)

Comment: Like the answer, but as an explanation you could add that there is a difference between pointers to member functions and non-member functions. That is the reason for the different treatment. Member functions taking the implicit `this` pointer

Comment: I suspected the user may have known he had to pass in obj somewhere as he tried obj.print_a, it is just an invalid syntax.